# Different answer for including constant prefactor in NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration

I'm attempting to integrate a function of the form $c_2\cdot g(x,a,b,c)$ such that
$$f(x) = c_1\cdot x\iiint_S c_2\cdot g(x,a,b,c)\ da\ db\ dc$$
where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are both constants such that $c_1\cdot c_2\sim \mathcal{O}(1)$ but the values of $c_1$ and $c_2$ themselves are *very* small and large respectively. Additionally, here $S$ is some nontrivial set of inequalities so I am using a region for integration.

My code is of the general form:

```
  PreFac[x_?NumberQ] := c1*x;
  Intgrd[x_?NumberQ,a_, b_, c_] = c2*g[x,a,b,c];
  sig = 0.1;
    
  R = ImplicitRegion[{-b - a (1 - 2*sig) < c < b  
  && -(a/2) (1 - 2*sig) < b < a 
  && 0 < a < Infinity }, {a, b, c}];
    
  f[x_?NumberQ]:= PreFac[x]*NIntegrate[Intgrd[x,a,b,c], {a,b,c} \[Element] R,
  Method ->{Automatic}, MaxRecursion -> 5, AccuracyGoal -> 4];
```

I've been able to get this to work for my function $g(x)$, though it takes ~6 seconds for each evaluation of $f(x)$. Plotting $f(x)$ also produces the curve I was expecting.
***However***, in order to improve speed I tried placing the constant (w.r.t integration) pre-factor $c_1 x$ *into*  the integrand i.e. I adjusted the above line:

```
f[x_?NumberQ]:= NIntegrate[PreFac[x]*Intgrd[x,a, b, c], {a,b,c} \[Element] R,
Method ->{Automatic}, MaxRecursion -> 5, AccuracyGoal -> 4];
```

This gave me a 10x speed increase, but produced *different* answers for $f(x)$ including producing a fairly different curve. Below you can see the difference.
The *top* plot is *with* the pre-factor in `NIntegrate` where the bottom plot has the pre-factor on the outside. Comparing the the result I am trying to reproduce, the *bottom* plot is the curve I was expecting.

[image: CodeOutput]

**Question:** What's going on here? How can I rewrite things so that shuffling constants around doesn't change the answer?

Below I'll place the explicit functions I'm using, but they're *very* messy.

```
  Prefac[x_?NumberQ] := 6.33542*10^(-9) x;
  Intgrd[x_?NumberQ,a_, b_, c_] :=  337500000 Sqrt[5]/(a^2 (a + b + c)^2 Pi) (a - b)(a - c)(b - c)
      (a^4 + b^4 - b^2 c^2 + c^4 - a^2 (b^2 + c^2))*Exp[-150 (2 a^2 + 2 b^2 - b c + 2 c^2 - a (b + c))] 
      * Abs[ExpIntegralE[1/3, (0. + 387.273 I) (((a + b + c)/a)^(3/2))^(1/3) x] 
      - 2 ExpIntegralE[1/3, (0. + 1095.37 I) (((a + b + c)/a)^(3/2))^(1/3)x]]^2
      * HeavisideTheta[144 - 5 ((a + b + c)/a)^(3/2)]
```

Comment: The `AccuracyGoal -> 4` determines different stopping criteria with and without the prefactor. Perhaps that's why there are different results. For a simple example, compare `10^-9 NIntegrate[Exp[Sin[x]], {x, 0, 25}, AccuracyGoal -> 4]` and 
`NIntegrate[10^-9 Exp[Sin[x]], {x, 0, 25}, AccuracyGoal -> 4]`.  And then with `NIntegrate[10^-9 Exp[Sin[x]], {x, 0, 25}, AccuracyGoal -> 4 + 9]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yup, that seems to be it. I removed the accuracy goal from both calculations as got the same answer. The downside is they both took a long time (93 sec). Is there anything you recommend which will let me get the same result, but also reduce run time? Thanks!

Comment: Reduce `PrecisionGoal` to maybe `PrecisionGoal -> 3`.  `PrecisionGoal` uses relative precision as a stopping criterion; `AccuracyGoal` uses absolute error as a stopping criterion.  You could try a lower precision goal, but sometimes the error estimates are off when the sampling is sparse. It might underestimate the error and stop before it gets an accurate result, just as it did with `AccuracyGoal -> 4`.

Comment: Approximating `ExpIntegralE[]` with `ei1B = NDSolveValue[ SetPrecision[ {y'[z] == D[ExpIntegralE[1/3, (0. + 387.273 I) z], z],  y[0.01*0.022360679774997876`] ==  ExpIntegralE[1/3, (0. + 387.273 I) 0.01*0.022360679774997876`]},   32],  y, {z, 0.01*0.022360679774997876`, 2*0.08660254037844388`},  WorkingPrecision -> 32, Method -> "Extrapolation",  InterpolationOrder -> All]` and similarly for the other one, will cut the time in half, roughly. `ExpIntegralE[]` seems slow. You might try skipping the region and using `{a, 0, Infinity}, {b, -(1/2) a (1 - 2 sig), a}, {c, -b - 
  a (1 - 2 sig), b}`